# SQL show a column based on another table's column values

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-pivot

ORACLE SQL with my semi-beginner's experience.

I have table `Credits` one row per ID:

```
ID, ArtCred, BizCred, HumCred, NatCred, TekCred, GenCred
5001, 12, 7.5, 12, 14, 11, 9
5002, 10.5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 3
```

with an ID for each student and the credits for each course group.

Students can select a course group(s) to concentrate on from the GrpChoice table which shows their choice and the date when they made it.

```
ID, GroupChoice, DateChoice
5001, ART, 3/3/2010
5001, BIZ, 5/5/2015
5001, NAT, 6/23/2022
5002, ART, 6/23/2023
```

I can query every group's credits for each student even if not chosen):

```
SELECT
    ID,
    GroupChoice, 
    artcred,
    bizcred,
    humcred,
    natcred,
    tekcred,
    gencred
FROM 
    Grpchoice
INNER JOIN 
    Credits ON GrpChoice.ID = Credits.ID
ORDER BY 
    Grpchoice.datechoice Desc
```

```
ID   Group   Art     Biz     Hum     Nat    Tek     Gen
5001  TEK   12  7.5 12  14  11  9
5001  HHS   12  7.5 12  14  11  9
5001  BIZ   12  7.5 12  14  11  9
5001  ART   12  7.5 12  14  11  9
5002  ART       10.5     6       5       4       6      3
```

but I need to show for each ID and the credits achieved for the GrpChoice (sort by Date desc):

I want to see only for ID 5001:

```
 ART 12
 BIZ 7.5
 NAT 14
```

For ID 5002:

```
 ART 10.5
```

I've tried a PIVOT but since the GrpChoice value can change, I don't think I can use that. Unless I set up my data differently to pivot on the ID... I have only read about pivots.

CASE GRPCHOICE won't work because it won't modify the SELECT based on its value (I can't "SELECT CASE When GrpChoice = "Art" then SELECT artCHr, WHEN GrpChoice="BIZ" then SELECT bizCHr...").

I've looked at OVER (PARTITION BY) but I'm not seeing how that would work.

Suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: The problem is the database design. In the table GrpChoice ART, BIZ, NAT, etc. are data. In the table Credits they are structure (ArtCred, BizCred, etc.). Decide whether these subjetcs shall be part of the database structure or just data in the database. Don't mix this. I suggest to make the subjects data, so you can easily add a subject or remove a subject any time. This would mean you'd change the Credits table to have three columns: student ID, subject, and credit.

Comment: In their answer, MT0 shows how to convert the Credits table on-the-fly. But it would be better to change the table in the database, so the query does not have to know which subjects exist in the database.

Comment: There are two sets of data. The group choice is the group name as data. The credits earned for each group is then data with the group name as subject / field name. The groups are constant and each group has a credit value. But the choice can change and have multiple values over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actuaaly, with sample data provided, you could use CASE expression to get your expected result:

```sql
WITH        --  Sample Data
    credits AS
        (
            Select 5001 "ID", 12 "ARTCRED", 7.5 "BIZCRED", 12 "HUMCRED", 14 "NATCRED", 11 "TEKCRED", 9 "GENCRED" From Dual Union All
            Select 5002 "ID", 10.5 "ARTCRED", 6 "BIZCRED",  5 "HUMCRED",  4 "NATCRED",  6 "TEKCRED", 3 "GENCRED" From Dual 
        ),
    grp_choices AS
        (
            Select 5001 "ID", 'ART' "GROUPCHOICE", To_Date('03.03.2010', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "DATECHOICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5001 "ID", 'BIZ' "GROUPCHOICE", To_Date('05.05.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "DATECHOICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5001 "ID", 'NAT' "GROUPCHOICE", To_Date('23.06.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "DATECHOICE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5002 "ID", 'ART' "GROUPCHOICE", To_Date('23.06.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "DATECHOICE" From Dual
        )
--
--  M a i n   S Q L
Select  c.ID, 
        g.GROUPCHOICE, 
        CASE g.GROUPCHOICE
            WHEN 'ART' THEN c.ARTCRED
            WHEN 'BIZ' THEN c.BIZCRED
            WHEN 'HUM' THEN c.HUMCRED
            WHEN 'NAT' THEN c.NATCRED
            WHEN 'TEK' THEN c.TEKCRED
            WHEN 'GEN' THEN c.GENCRED
        ELSE 0
        END "CREDIT"
From    credits c
Inner Join grp_choices g ON(g.ID = c.ID)
--
--  R e s u l t :
        ID GROUP     CREDIT
---------- ----- ----------
      5001 ART           12
      5001 BIZ          7.5
      5001 NAT           14
      5002 ART         10.5
```

Comment: That is why I asked. I knew there had to be a simple way to crack this nut. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNPIVOT`, rather than `PIVOT`, and then join the two tables:

```sql
SELECT c.id, subject, credit
FROM   credits
       UNPIVOT (
         credit FOR subject IN (
           artcred As 'ART',
           bizcred AS 'BIZ',
           humcred AS 'HUM',
           natcred AS 'NAT',
           tekcred AS 'TEK',
           gencred AS 'GEN'
         )
       ) c
       INNER JOIN grpchoice g
       ON c.id = g.id AND c.subject = g.groupchoice
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE credits (ID, ArtCred, BizCred, HumCred, NatCred, TekCred, GenCred) AS
SELECT 5001, 12, 7.5, 12, 14, 11, 9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5002, 10.5, 6, 5, 4, 6, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE GrpChoice (ID, GroupChoice, DateChoice) AS
SELECT 5001, 'ART', DATE '2010-03-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5001, 'BIZ', DATE '2015-05-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5001, 'NAT', DATE '2022-06-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5002, 'ART', DATE '2023-06-23' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | SUBJECT | CREDIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5001 | ART | 12 |
| 5001 | BIZ | 7.5 |
| 5001 | NAT | 14 |
| 5002 | ART | 10.5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MZp8UU7v)

Comment: Interesting. I would never have guessed there was an UNPIVOT statement. That result looks perfect.